# saving 2D animation with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, plot

i have a problem. I would like to salve a mp4 gif of the animated plot.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import pylab as pl
from numpy import array, zeros, linspace, meshgrid



conc_profile2D_FDA = np.load('matrixFDA.npy')
conc_profile2D_FA = np.load('matrixFA.npy')
conc_profile2D_F = np.load('matrixF.npy')

x = np.linspace(0, 170, 55)
y = np.linspace(0, 7.25E-3, 51)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(y, x)

fig, axes = pl.subplots(1, 3) 


def animate(i): 
    Z = conc_profile2D_FDA[i,1:,:]
    Z1 = conc_profile2D_FA[i,1:,:]
    Z2 = conc_profile2D_F[i,1:,:]
    c = axes[0].contourf(X, Y, Z, 20, cmap='jet', vmin=0, vmax=0.000038)
    c1 = axes[1].contourf(X, Y, Z1, 20, cmap='jet', vmin=0, vmax=0.000004)
    c2 = axes[2].contourf(X, Y, Z2, 20, cmap='jet', vmin=0, vmax=0.0000007)



    return c
    return c1
    return c2

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=202)
anim.save('animation.mp4', fps=60, dpi=600,)
plt.show()
```

plt.show(), show me the live graph correctly, but when I uncomment "anim.save", this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Dropbox\uni\Magistrale chimica dei materiali\Tirocinio e tesi\lavoro_tesi\Animazione 2D.py", line 38, in <module>
anim.save('animation.mp4', fps=60, dpi=600,)
File "c:\env\diffusion\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1251, in save
    with writer.saving(self._fig, filename, dpi):
File "c:\python27\Lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
File "c:\env\diffusion\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 233, in saving
    self.setup(fig, outfile, dpi, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\env\diffusion\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 941, in setup
    raise ValueError("outfile must be *.htm or *.html")
ValueError: outfile must be *.htm or *.html
```

I tried to change the extension from .mp4 to .html, but the error change:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
File "c:\env\diffusion\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1218
    warnings.warn("MovieWriter %s unavailable" % writer)
UserWarning: MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable
```

How Can I do? I read on animation.Funcanimation documentation that the extension .mp4 is ok. 
Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video manipulation with matplotlib is based on calls to `ffmpeg`. You need to install that package.

If you use Anaconda: `conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg`.
If you use Ubuntu (or derived): `apt install ffmpeg`.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have windows but i don't use anaconda. I searched online how to install this encoder: simply copy files inside a directory and add the path in environmental variable! Now work good